# Laravel4 время отклика

Tags: laravel, php

Народ, помогайте )

1. Использую Laravel 4.
2. На клиенте делаю ajax-запрос на сервер.
3. На сервере с помощью curl отправляю post-запрос на backend и забираю инфу.
4. Парсю на сервере.
5. Отправляю на клиент.

Все работает, но не очень хорошо!
А именно не устраивает время выполнения запроса.
Т.к. проект довольно-таки нагруженный, в некоторых случаях ожидание доходит до минуты...

Посмотрев статистику, заметил, что 95% времени запроса выполняется некий метод компонента

```
Symfony -  
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Proxy SessionHandlerProxy::read()
```

Есть какие-нибудь мысли?
Почему он вообще появляется?
Как решить проблему?

Comment: Если допустить, что 95% времени запроса уходит на SessionHandlerInterface, то осмелюсь предположить, что в условиях высоконагруженного проекта открывается очень много сессий, которые соххраняются в файлах на диске. И каждый раз на поиск уходит очень много времени. Если файловая система неэффективна, в данном случае можно подумать о реализации своего session_handler на основе SQL или NoSQL.

Comment: Получается, что в моем случае и вообще в высоконагруженных проектах хранить информацию в сессиях не эффективно?
Или же у меня не верная реализация сессий?
Выбор драйвера сессии как-нибудь повлияет на скорость работы?
У меня стоит по умолчанию  
    native

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [memcache или redis](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session#session-drivers) для хранения данных сессий.

Comment: В проекте работают параллельно до 10 ajax-запросов. 

memcache позволяет выполнять одновременную запись?

Comment: memcache - мультитредовый по умолчанию. Задайте количество тредов, равное количеству доступных ядер и получите количество реально одновременных записей. Другое дело, что оно работает очень быстро (ибо в памяти) и, даже при последовательной записи, падение производительности при 10-50-100 конкурентных сессиях для записи сессионных данных (простите уж за каламбур) Вы вряд ли заметите...

Comment: тут надо добавить только то, что в memcache (я так и не разобрался, что за сервис redis и что у него с постоянным хранением данных) можно потерять все сессии разом в случае остановки сервиса (перезагрузка сервера, например) - в этом случае слетят все аутентификации и все содержимое сессий, поэтому нужно рассматривать такой вариант.

Comment: Redis persistence: http://redis.io/topics/persistence
Для  memcached, я помню, что были какие-то доп. инструменты для поддержания постоянного хранения и восстановления данных после ребута сервера - нужно гуглить.

Comment: Подводя итог.
Получается, что вынос сессии в бд и memcache решают мою проблему.
(Спасибо Etki, я понял что косяк в том, что на запись файл просто не откроется пока не закроется в предыдущем запросе).

Предпочтение отдам memcache из-за скорости, т.к. при потере данных ничего страшного в моем проекте не происходит.

Comment: @sepgg, примите тогда ответ @smgladkovskiy, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Это частая проблема, сессия читается из файла, который читается медленно и блокируется (читай - не может читаться двумя запросами одновременно). При наличии кучи запросов на странице это превращается в проблему. Рекомендуемое решение - вынос сессии в БД, sqlite или основную, однако при этом надо очень осторожно работать с записью, чтобы случайно не переписать только что записанное значение.