# Проблема с memcached

Tags: laravel, сессия, memcached, php

Народ, [продолжение вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/410789/php-laravel4-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Прошу еще подсказать, где может быть косяк.

Реализовал хранение сессии в memcached.
Пишу в сессию `Session::put('key','value')`, причем внутри метода, в котором она записывается, чтение `Session::get('key')` видит `value`, а в другом методе уже не видит...

Вопрос: куда девается?

ПС.
До реализации memcached такой проблемы не было.
Кэш - 2Гб, `value` максимум 300Кб
Lifetime 20min

Comment: @sepgg, будьте добры, приведите пример кода. Где сейчас читается, а где нет - непонятно.

Comment: Дело в блокировках, в общем.  
Ок. Тогда, может, подскажет, кто наиболее подходящую реализацию.

В общем, бэкэнд сильно тупит, поэтому последовательные запросы не подходят.
Нужно отправить несколько параллельных запросов, при этом ответ каждого нужно БЫСТРО сохранить.